# Node - Unexpected or invalid token in line 1, after reinstalling Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a JavaScript file that I could run just fine yesterday. I reinstalled Windows last night, reinstalled Node this morning, and I'm trying to run the same JavaScript file now, but its giving me an error.

```
$ node index.js
C:\Users\<user-name>\Google Drive\Projects\<blah>-coding\index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Comment: See if your file editor uses UTF-8 with BOM. If that is the case, change it to without BOM, save and try again

Comment: @JetpackPony How can I check this on a Windows machine?

Comment: Depends on the editor you are using. In Notepad++ for example you can choose "UTF-8 without BOM" in Encoding menu.

Answer (score 0):

code is Unicode and not working, just save as UTF-8, working great!